# biblatex author field with romanised name and original name

Tags: biblatex, japanese

I am studying with japanese, french and english sources.
I am looking for a way to get with biblatex a way to show in the case of Japanese the romanised name, followed by the original one.
And the same anything that need translation for non-native.
For example : 
Kishi, Akinori 喜始照宣, « Geijutsukei daigaku shusshinsha to rōdō » 芸術系大学出身者と労働 (Diplômés d’écoles d’art et travail)

In this example, "Kishi, Akinori" is the romanisation of 喜始照宣. "Geijutsukei daigaku shusshinsha to rōdō" isthe romanisation of 芸術系大学出身者と労働, and "Diplômés d’écoles d’art et travail" the french translation.

There is an old answer using the vform option, but it is not a real one, non-recognized in the later version of biblatex.
This is an entry designed like this old answer, with special fields as _romanised, or _translation_french.

```
@BOOK{itou_seiu_semee_no_onna,
    LANGID = {japanese},
    AUTHOR = {伊藤晴雨},
    AUTHOR_romanised = {Itō, Seiu},
    TITLE = {責め絵の女―伊藤晴雨写真帖},
    TITLE_romanised = {seme.e no onna~---~itō seiu shashinjō},
    TITLE_translated_french = {femmes de peinture de blâme~---~collection photographique de itō seiu},
    PUBLISHER = {新潮社},
    PUBLISHER_romanised = {Shinchōsha},
    DATE = {1996-08},
    PAGETOTAL = {141}
}
```

Does anyone have an Idea to insert romanised and original name with biblatex ?

Comment: The current release version of `biblatex` does not support these field modifiers like `_romanised` etc. But there is an experimental `multiscript` version that does. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416. `multiscript` `biblatex` is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/experimental/, Biber at https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/experimental/. The code is still highly experimental, but the author needs feedback by people with real-life use cases to move development forward.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a rough example with the new 4.0 experimental versions of `biblatex/biber`. There is no attempt to make this a clean style - it's just to show the mechanisms. All I have done is to slightly modify the generic macros that print various fields. A real solution would need a japanese `.lbx` file for biblatex to define date formats and strings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common, TeX}]{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=1]{SimSun}
\usepackage[french,english,japanese]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{itou_seiu_semee_no_onna,
    LANGID                  = {ja-jp},
    AUTHOR                  = {伊藤晴雨},
    AUTHOR_transcription    = {Itō, Seiu},
    TITLE                   = {責め絵の女―伊藤晴雨写真帖},
    TITLE_transcription     = {seme.e no onna~---~itō seiu shashinjō},
    TITLE_translation_fr    = {femmes de peinture de blâme~---~collection photographique de itō seiu},
    PUBLISHER               = {新潮社},
    PUBLISHER_transcription = {Shinchōsha},
    DATE                    = {1996-08}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
      {\printnames{labelname}%
       \mkbibparens{\printnames[][][transcription]{author}}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
  {\printnames{author}%
   \mkbibparens{\printnames[][][transcription]{author}}%
   \iffieldundef{authortype}
   {}
   {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
 {}}

\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \printtext[title]{%
       \mkbibparens{\printfield[titlecase][transcription]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase][transcription]{subtitle}}}%
     % \printtext[title]{%
     %   \mkbibparens{\printfield[titlecase][translation][fr]{title}%
     %    \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
     %    \printfield[titlecase][translation][fr]{subtitle}}}%
    \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \mkbibparens{\printlist[][][transcription]{publisher}}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\cite{itou_seiu_semee_no_onna}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```